# Why div's text and button's text size differ if it both are set to 1em?

Tags: css, button, font-size

Why the button's text size is bigger than div->span's text size when both is set to 1em? How can I make them rendered to the same size?
Now firefox shows me the div's text as 17px high and 20px for the button's text.

```css
.selectDateRangeBtn {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}

#searchRangeControl {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
    <div id="searchRangeControl" >
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;<span>Some text</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>

    <button class="selectDateRangeBtn">2019-01-01</button>
```

Comment: Button size is relative to font-size. Try changing button font size, you'll see.

Comment: What is the class `fa fa-calender` doing

Comment: @Flash That's a fontawesome icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `font-size` is the same but the button is having a default `font-family` set by the user agent which is different from your div.

[image]

Use the same `font-family` (reset the `font` property) and you will have the same text size

```css
.selectDateRangeBtn {
    font:initial; /* reset the font */
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}

#searchRangeControl {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchRangeControl" >
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;<span>2019-01-01</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>

    <button class="selectDateRangeBtn">2019-01-01</button>
```

Comment: This was the problem indeed.  Also Firefox inspector tricked me as it showed the font-family as inherited from body.